# Using case to create a new column MySQL

Tags: mysql, case

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to create a new column using values from another column.

I'm using something like this.

```
Select 
a.idclientecrm,
(case
when a.titulo like '%Mensual'       then 'Mensual'
when a.titulo like '%Trimestral'    then 'Trimestral'
when a.titulo like '%Semestral'     then 'Semestral'
when a.titulo like '%Anual'         then 'Anual'
else null
end) as Periodo_Producto
from tareas a
```

When I find the word *Mensual* in **a.titulo** I need the word 'Mensual' in the new column and so on for every different time period (*trimestral*, *semestral* and *anual*).

The "like" part doesn't seem to work, I also tried with **contains** but I can't make it work either.

Hope it's understandable.

Comment: You say the `LIKE` doesn't work.  What does it do?  Can you give some sample output from when you run the SQL above including the a.titulo column?

Comment: Are you expecting the word at the end of the title or the beginning or anywhere in the title?  You might have the wildcard in the wrong place.

Comment: Good point bluefeet.  @Pietro, you probably want the % sign after the word or on both sides (depending on what you are looking for).

Comment: The word I look for is in the end of every word, but without the % at the end of the *like* the result was all nulls. Maybe there's a space (checked and they didn't have). Do you guys know if the like is case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `%` at both ends of `String`

```
   Select 
    a.idclientecrm,
    (case
    when a.titulo like '%Mensual%'       then 'Mensual'
    when a.titulo like '%Trimestral%'    then 'Trimestral'
    when a.titulo like '%Semestral%'     then 'Semestral'
    when a.titulo like '%Anual%'         then 'Anual'
    else null
    end) as Periodo_Producto
    from tareas a
```

Comment: I swear I tried it like that and didn't work. Just what I needed :)

Comment: put your `table` data to identify the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need a '%' sign at the end of the comparison string (as well as the start) for the comparison to check anywhere in the string - at the moment it is only checking that the string *ends* with the time period word. Try:

```
Select 
a.idclientecrm,
(case
when a.titulo like '%Mensual%'       then 'Mensual'
when a.titulo like '%Trimestral%'    then 'Trimestral'
when a.titulo like '%Semestral%'     then 'Semestral'
when a.titulo like '%Anual%'         then 'Anual'
end) as Periodo_Producto
from tareas a
```

(Also, the `else null` was unnecessary - `case` returns null where there is no matching condition, by default.)

Comment: I swear I tried it like that and didn't work. Just what I needed :)

Comment: I only chose the first one because he answered first. But both are the same. Thnx anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Use % at both ends.

Try this:

```
Select 
a.idclientecrm,
(case
when a.titulo like '%Mensual%'       then 'Mensual'
when a.titulo like '%Trimestral%'    then 'Trimestral'
when a.titulo like '%Semestral%'     then 'Semestral'
when a.titulo like '%Anual%'         then 'Anual'
else null
end) as Periodo_Producto
from tareas a
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9e81/2) for this.

Hope this works as per your need. Thanks!